# Storing line as variable in C

Tags: c

Let's say I must read, line by line, a ".txt" file that gets me the lowest results of a bunch and store them as variables in order to print them afterwards (both the average speed in ms, as integer, extracted through the "velocidad_media" function, and the corresponding line of the file that's being read while offering such result):

```
int best_response = velocidad_media(fgets(ipresp, sizeof(ipresp), responses));
char best_ip;
responses = fopen("ips_responden.txt", "r");
while (fgets(ipresp, sizeof(ipresp), responses))
{
    int response1 = velocidad_media(ipresp);
    if (response1 < best_response) {
        best_response = response1;
        best_ip = response1;
    }
    printf("\n    Velocidad de respuesta media: %d ms.\n", best_response);
    printf("    IP seleccionada: %s", best_ip);
}
```

So far I'm able to store such average time (as best_response). But I'm getting confused with the "best_ip" bit. I don't know how to initialize nor implement the variable to my own code in order to also store the line I'm actually reading and gives me the "best_response" result.

Comment: To store a line, you need a buffer that can store a string, not only one character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

- Allocate buffer to store a string, not only one char.
- Store the line, not something that is obtained by processing the line.

Also you should check if `fopen()` is successful.

Try this:

```
int best_response = 0;
char best_ip[sizeof(ipresp)] = "";
int best_valid = 0;
responses = fopen("ips_responden.txt", "r");
if (responses != NULL)
{
    while (fgets(ipresp, sizeof(ipresp), responses))
    {
        int response1 = velocidad_media(ipresp);
        if (!best_valid || response1 < best_response) {
            best_response = response1;
            strcpy(best_ip, ipresp);
            best_valid = 1;
        }
        printf("\n    Velocidad de respuesta media: %d ms.\n", best_response);
        printf("    IP seleccionada: %s", best_ip);
    }
}
```

Also note that you should add `#include <string.h>` to use `strcpy()`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. As I see, this works well and it prints the values of average time and the corresponding IP inside a loop, I mean, going through the different IP's listed in my .txt file. But my idea was rather going through the IP files, extracting the average time of response, and just storing & printing the average and corresponding IP of the "winner" (i.e., the lowest value of average speed). Do I make sense? (Not too fluent in English at times)

Comment: just put the two `printf`lines out of the while loop.